# Properties of the matrix square root

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

In a paper I am reading, it is claimed that if $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are positive definite, then
$$ A^{1/2} (A^{−1/2} B A^{−1/2})^{1/2} A^{1/2} = A (A^{-1}B)^{1/2} $$
because of the properties of the principal matrix square root, but I am not sure how this equality can be proved. Has anybody got a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we have 
$$A^{-1}B=A^{-1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})A^{1/2}=:A^{-1/2}CA^{1/2}.$$ 
So if $C=QDQ^*$ is an eigen-decomposition of the HPD matrix $C$, then
$$A^{-1}B=A^{-1/2}QDQ^*A^{1/2}=XDX^{-1}, \quad X:=A^{-1/2}Q,$$
is the eigen-decomposition of $A^{-1}B$. With $(A^{-1}B)^{1/2}=XD^{1/2}X^{-1}$, we get
$$
A(A^{-1}B)^{1/2}=AXD^{1/2}X^{-1}=A^{1/2}QD^{1/2}Q^*A^{1/2}=A^{1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})^{1/2}A^{1/2}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Pre-multiply both sides by $A^{-1}$
$$
  A^{-1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})^{1/2}A^{1/2} = (A^{-1}B)^{1/2}
$$
Now square both sides
$$\eqalign{
  A^{-1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})^{1/2}A^{1/2}\,\,\,A^{-1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})^{1/2}A^{1/2} &= (A^{-1}B) \cr
  A^{-1/2}(A^{-1/2}BA^{-1/2})A^{1/2} &= (A^{-1}B) \cr
  A^{-1}B &= (A^{-1}B) \cr
}$$
These algebraic manipulations hinge on the fact that, for a positive definite matrix, $A^{1/2}$ and $A^{-1/2}$ can be uniquely defined (as the principal matrix square root).

Comment: $A^{-1} B$ is not symmetric in general, however it is similar to the positive definite matrix $A^{-1/2} B A^{-1/2}$. in particular its eigenvalues are all positive, and we can define its principal square root using the holomorphic functional calculus and the principal branch of the function $\sqrt{z}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very general theorem from Nick Higham's [book](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898717778).

Let $X\in{\mathbb C}^{m\times n}$
and $Y\in{\mathbb C}^{n\times m}$
and let $f$ be defined on the spectra of both $XY$ and $YX.$

Then
$$\eqalign{
X\,f(YX) &= f(XY)\,X \\
}$$
Now rewrite the LHS of your product expression
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
P = A^{1/2}\LR{\c{A^{1/2}}A^{-1}BA^{-1/2}}^{1/2}\c{A^{1/2}} \\
}$$
Make the following identifications
$$\eqalign{
X &= A^{1/2},\quad Y = \LR{A^{-1}BA^{-1/2}},\quad f(z) = {\sqrt z} \\
}$$
and apply Higham's theorem
$$\eqalign{
P &= A^{1/2}\c{A^{1/2}}\LR{A^{-1}BA^{-1/2}\c{A^{1/2}}}^{1/2} \\
  &= A\LR{A^{-1}B}^{1/2} \\
}$$
This assumes that $A^{-1/2}$ is well defined, which it is for PD matrices.

Answer (score 1):

This is true if and only if $A$ and $B$ commute.

If they do commute, they are simultaneously unitarily diagonalisable. Hence the equality can be handled like the scalar case and it's trivial.

If they don't commute, the $A^{-1}B$ on the RHS is not Hermitian and $(A^{-1}B)^{1/2}$ is not well defined.

Comment: @Ramanujan It doesn't. $(A^{-1}B)^{1/2}$ in general is not defined because $A^{-1}B$ may possess multiple square roots. What the other comments or answers show is that it is possible to pick a square root $R$ of $A^{-1}B$ such that $A^{1/2} (A^{−1/2}B A^{−1/2})^{1/2} A^{1/2}=AR$.